# Automatically adjust scaling of a display when a second monitor is plugged in [Windows 10]

Tags: windows, display, scaling

I currently have a work laptop that I would like to have the scaling set to 125% when it is plugged into another monitor/docked, and set to 100% when it is not plugged in. Does anyone know of any ways to do this automatically? The operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: @jd-rogers Did you find a solution to this? That's exactly the thing I'm just researching...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this.

Scaling is a function of the User ID and not the Monitor used.

So you will need to set the scaling when you change monitors.